# Mongoose giving error not connetig to server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Connection code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");

const Cat = mongoose.model("Cat", { name: String });

const kitty = new Cat({ name: "Zildjian" });
kitty.save().then(() => console.log("meow"));
```

I have defined path variable for MongoDB in Environment variables and it's working, I have checked it by running `mongod` in cmd and it's not giving error.
[image: error in console]

[image: here is my powershell screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

changing the connection url make my code run successfully..

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test");

const Cat = mongoose.model("Cat", { name: String });

const kitty = new Cat({ name: "Zildjian" });
kitty.save().then(() => console.log("meow"));
```

I have changed url `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test` from `mongodb://localhost:27017/test` and it started working